# Direct query returns data but inner stored procedure query does not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetGroupUsers]
    @GroupName VARCHAR(500) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    PRINT @GroupName

    -- get group users
    DECLARE @GroupUsers TABLE
        (
            GroupId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
            GroupName VARCHAR(500),
            UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
        )

    INSERT INTO @GroupUsers 
        SELECT
            GroupId, GroupName, UserId
        FROM 
            AllGroupUsers agu
        WHERE 
            (@GroupName IS NULL OR agu.[GroupName] LIKE @GroupName + '%')

    SELECT * FROM @GroupUsers
END
```

For some reason, the stored procedure above isn't returning data when I execute it through the SSMS test dialogue with a `@GroupName` value of `_MY_TEST` although data is returned if I run the following query directly from a different query window:

```
select * 
from AllGroupUsers agu
where agu.[GroupName] like '_MY_TEST' + '%'
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

The `print @GroupName` command is printing the expected value and I also tried to change the `@GroupName` type from `VARCHAR(500)` to `NVARCHAR(500)` but still no results are returned from the stored procedure?

Comment: Perhaps you are connected to different databases?

Comment: can you explain what you are doing here (@GroupName IS NULL OR

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik he's returning all rows if the parameter is null and if the parameter is not null, then only where GroupName begins with that parameter value

Comment: Side note @user9393635 I don't see any reason for the table variable here. Have you right clicked on the procedure and selected `Script stored procedure as....` to ensure the correct version is actually created on the DB? It's not uncommon to make changes and forget to overwrite the original object

Comment: We no sample of data, my guess is the GroupID, is not unique when enough things are returned. So by forcing that constraint on the table you stop the result. Change those to something like BIGINT or drop the not needed step as @scsimon said.

Comment: There is no constraint on the table.

Comment: Make sure GroupId  and UserId in AllGroupUsers  table are of type uniqueidentifier

Comment: can you add table DDL script with sample data because I try it on sample data it is working fine